# How to store an array with user input values

Tags: java, arrays, serialization

I'm taking a java course in school and was given this question:
"Write a program that stores an array of the five int values 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5, a Date object for current time, and the double value 5.5 in the file named Exercise17_05.dat."

My professor wanted to modify this by saying, "We will change things up a little on this in that you need to let the user enter in their name and enter the five (5) integer values along with the other two items mentioned."

I figured out how to do the original problem thanks to the amazing people on here. I tried to modify the program with what I know but keep getting "Exception in Thread" errors.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:197)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readLong(DataInputStream.java:416)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readDouble(DataInputStream.java:468)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readDouble(ObjectInputStream.java:3208)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readDouble(ObjectInputStream.java:1061)
    at cosc_hw17.COSC_HW17.main(COSC_HW17.java:75)
Java Result: 1
```

I know it has something to do with creating an array and the original reading from the file part. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

What I have is attached below. I updated the code and am still having issues. Error is reading that it cannot find symbol for the numbers' "readObject"

```html
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;

public class COSC_HW17 
{
    // main method
    public static void main(String[] args) 
         throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException   
    {
        // create scanner
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        
        // stores integers in array
        double [] numbers = new double [5]; 
        
        // stores the returned array from method
        double[] ret;
        
        //Create an output stream for file
        ObjectOutputStream output 
            = new ObjectOutputStream(
                  new FileOutputStream("Exercise17_05.dat", true));
              
        // Ask user for name
        System.out.println("Please Enter Name:");
        String name = input.next();
        
        
        // Ask user for numbers
        System.out.println("Input Five Integer Values:");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            numbers[i] = input.nextInt();
            
        }
        
        
        //Write to file
        // 1. Write name
        output.writeUTF(name);
        // 2. Write int array object
        output.writeObject(numbers);
        // 3. Write double
        output.writeDouble(5.5);
        // 4. Write date object
        output.writeObject(new java.util.Date());
        // 5. Write utf string
        output.writeUTF("Exercise17_05.dat");

        // Close the stream
        output.close();

        //Create an input stream for file
        ObjectInputStream report 
            = new ObjectInputStream
                (new FileInputStream("Exercise17_05.dat"));

        // Read from file
        // 1. Read name
        System.out.println("Name: " + name);
        // 2. Read int array object
        int[] newNumbers = (int[]) (input.readObject());
        System.out.println("Integers: " + Arrays.toString(newNumbers));
        // 3. Read double
        double doubleValue = report.readDouble();
        System.out.println("Double value: " + doubleValue); 
        // 4. Read date object
        Date date = (java.util.Date) (report.readObject());
        System.out.println("DateTime: " + date);
        // 5. Read utf string
        String fileName = report.readUTF();
        System.out.println("File name: " + fileName);

        // Close the stream
        input.close();
    }
```

Comment: *"but keep getting "Exception in Thread" errors"* One of the most important things to learn is that when the compiler or runtime gives you an error message, you have to read it and understand it to work out what's wrong, and you have to tell other people what the error message was when you ask for their help, so they can work out what's wrong. Please edit your question to include the specific error message and stack trace.

Comment: @kaya3 There's the error message

Comment: Your program reads the double before the Date object, but the question says the Date object comes before the double. Could that be your problem?

Comment: No, because I could completely change the order and still get the same issues. When I run the basic question code, it works perfectly fine. But when I try to add user input, that's when everything goes haywire

Comment: Perhaps the problem is that you are printing the name and array from the first part of the program, instead of reading them from the file?

Comment: @kaya3 I think that's it. Because then it's doing ReadDouble but getting the name, which will cause a format exception. It needs a readUTF and ReadObject before readDouble.

Comment: @kaya3 I put in the original coding for reading the numbers and had a compile error stating "cannot find symbol"

Comment: You are mixing up the variables `input`, `report` and others. Try separating the segments into methods. 1) Read the stream 2) Write file 3) Print from file

Comment: Here's the other issue. You are writing an array of doubles and reading it and trying to cast it to an array of integers. Either write it as an array of integers or read it and cast to an array of doubles. So double[] newNumbers = (double[])report.readObject();

Answer (score 0):

You have to read exactly what you wrote. When you don't, the types don't match up. So for example originally when you did ReadDouble, it encountered the persons name, which led to the error with which you started the question. The most recent piece was more subtle, because an array of doubles was written, but you were attempting to read (cast) it as an array of integers.

So we just follow what happened in the writing:

```
// Read from file
        // 1. Read name
        String newName = report.readUTF(); 
        System.out.println("Name: " + newName);
        // 2. Read double array object
        ret = (double[])report.readObject();
        System.out.println("Integers: "+ Arrays.toString(ret));
        // 3. Read double
        double doubleValue = report.readDouble();
        System.out.println("Double value: " + doubleValue); 
        // 4. Read date object
        Date date = (java.util.Date) (report.readObject());
        System.out.println("DateTime: " + date);
        // 5. Read utf string
        String fileName = report.readUTF();
        System.out.println("File name: " + fileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually,there is a casual problem with the code.

```
 int[] newNumbers = (int[]) (input.readObject());
```

`readObject()` is a method of class `ObjectInputStream` in the `java.io.ObjectInputStream.ObjectInputStream`

`input` according to the code is object of Scanner class  from the `java.util.Scanner` package.

your statement `input.readObject()` is invalid as it seems to me and should raise:

> > The method readObject() is undefined for the type Scanner

And the Solution to the Question is:-

```
public class InputFile {



    public File data() throws IOException {
        Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);
        String Name="";
        int arr[]=new int[5];
        LocalDateTime mydate=LocalDateTime.now();
        double dou=5.5;
        System.out.println("please enter name");
        Name=scan.next();

         File file = new File("Exercise17_05.dat");
            if(file.createNewFile()){
                System.out.println("file.txt File Created in Project root directory");
            }else 
                System.out.println("File file.txt already exists in the project root directory");

            FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("Exercise17_05.dat");
            fos.write(Name.getBytes());
            for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
                System.out.println("please enter an integer numeral for the index:" +i);
                arr[i]=scan.nextInt();
                fos.write(arr[i]);
                }
System.out.println("the array is:::: " +Arrays.toStrings(arr));
            fos.write(mydate.toString().getBytes());
            fos.write(String.valueOf(dou).getBytes());

            return file;

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        InputFile data=new InputFile();
        data.data();


    }
}
```

I'd be glad to hear from you

Thank You.